# PHP if with an array SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've got a problem here

```
$resultContLog = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM dailyLogs WHERE data_log > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE and server_id_log=".$Fid.";");

$Adata = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultContLog);
if ($Adata > 0)
{
    echo 'OK';
}
else
{
   echo 'NOT OK';
}
```

My php function returns the number of rows; i did this to include new logs if it happen later than 10 minutes. The `if ($Adata > 0)` statement doesn't work properly. Can you guys help me, please?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `Count(*)` will always return one row either having 0 or more than 0, if `group by` clause not used. You need to see the count(*) value for the comparison.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns array or false. For `count()` query result is always an array, and it's bigger than 0.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for all you guys who tried to help me,i'll study the PDO from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check this , use this

Your need to check for count column you are getting from query if it is grater than zero, here it is used as alias of "total"

```
     $resultContLog=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM dailyLogs WHERE data_log > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE and server_id_log=".$Fid.";");
   $Adata=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultContLog);
  if($Adata['total'])
   {
  echo 'OK';
  }
else
{
 echo 'NOT OK';
 }
```

Comment: is it okay now @AbhikChakraborty

Answer (score 0):

You fetch the DB result as an array, thus you can count it:

```
if (count($Adata)) {
echo 'ok';
} else {
echo 'not ok'; 
}
```

Your query is a bit of a mess though. Maybe you could place some logic outside of the SQL.
The date function of PHP is flexible and works good with MySql.

```
// instead of NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 60*30);
```

Regards

*) edit: What @esqew said